# Python: Print dictionary using column formatting?

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to print a dictionary containing values

```
freqs = {',': 1, '8': 3, '0': 3, '6': 1, '7': 2, '!': 1, '+': 2, '#': 8, '%': 4, '.': 1, '&': 7, '/': 1, '1': 3, ')': 2, '"': 1, '-': 2, '3': 6, '5': 1, '$': 1, '2': 2, '*': 4, '4': 2, "'": 1, '9': 1, ':': 1}
```

This is a dictionary showing a character and the number of times it appears in a string. I want to show it to the user in two columns like so:

```
, (TAB) 1

8 (TAB) 3

0 (TAB) 3
```

etc..

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
freqs = {',': 1, '8': 3, '0': 3, '6': 1, '7': 2, '!': 1, '+': 2, '#': 8, '%': 4, '.': 1, '&': 7, '/': 1, '1': 3, ')': 2, '"': 1, '-': 2, '3': 6, '5': 1, '$': 1, '2': 2, '*': 4, '4': 2, "'": 1, '9': 1, ':': 1}

for k , v in freqs.iteritems(): # iterating freqa dictionary
        print k+"\t", v
```

---

**Output:**

```
!   1
#   8
"   1
%   4
$   1
'   1
&   7
)   2
+   2
*   4
-   2
,   1
/   1
.   1
1   3
0   3
3   6
2   2
5   1
4   2
7   2
6   1
9   1
8   3
:   1
```

Use **comma** `,` after print statement to print **keys** and **values** in same line, while `\t` is used for tabs.

```
print k+"\t", v
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python ≥ 3.6:

```
freqs = {',': 1, '8': 3, '0': 3, '6': 1, '7': 2, '!': 1, '+': 2, '#': 8, '%': 4, '.': 1, '&': 7, '/': 1, '1': 3, ')': 2, '"': 1, '-': 2, '3': 6, '5': 1, '$': 1, '2': 2, '*': 4, '4': 2, "'": 1, '9': 1, ':': 1}

for k, v in freqs.items():
    print(f'{k:<4} {v}')
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the `f'{k:<4}'` trick. I hadn't seen that before.

Answer (score 0):

```python
for item in freqs:
     print item, freqs[item]
```