# Is there a way I can assign two different values to a variable?

Tags: python

Sorry if the question is worded poorly but I basically want to create an array (not sure if correct terminology) that has the name of a creature in the first column, the name of an object in the second column, and then a number (drop chance) in the third column. Ideally I'd be able to refer to this array using the creature name in order to output the object name and perform calculations using the third column's number.

```
# create dictionary of boss names with a numerical value attached

boss_name = {
    "1": "Vindicta and Gorvek",
    "2": "Gregorovic",
    "3": "Helwyr",
    "4": "Twin Furies"
}
print("") # space

# print the table of bosses (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067061/python-print-dictionary-using-column-formatting/43550837)
for item in boss_name:
    print(item, boss_name[item])

print("") # space

boss_input = input("Please enter the number corresponding to the boss you would like to calculcate the drop rates for: ")
#boss_input = re.sub(r'[a-z,.]','',boss_input.lower()) # converts input into numbers only - this line is redundant?
boss_input_integer = int(boss_input) # converts the input into an integer

# input error check
print(len(boss_name))
input_error = True # set default state

while input_error == True: # when an invalid input is made, this section will loop continuously until a valid one is entered

    if boss_input_integer in range (1,len(boss_name)+1):
        print(f"You have selected {boss_name.get(boss_input)}")
        input_error = False # The input is valid, therefore no input error was made
    else:
        print(f"Invalid input. Please choose a number between 1 and {len(boss_name)}") # Error message for when a number is entered that is greater than the number of entries in the boss list
        boss_input = input("Please enter the number corresponding to the boss you would like to calulcate the drop rates for: ") # allows the user to input a new value
        boss_input_integer = int(boss_input)
    


# Function 1: Boss pet chance calculator

pet_item_info = {
    "Vindicta and Gorvek" : "Imbued blade slice" : "1/2000",
    "Gregorovic" : "Faceless mask" "1/1000"
}
```

So when I enter for example 2, the first dictionary takes that value as "Gregorovic". Then it would check the array (under Function 1) for where Gregorovic is listed in the first column, and would then output Faceless mask and 1/1000, for example "You have selected Gregorovic; Faceless mask has a drop rate of 1/1000". I know I can't use a library while using 3 columns, but I find it easier to visualise my problem.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It seems that you need to learn more about Python data structures.  What you describe sounds like a spreadsheet of three columns.  This could be three parallel lists, or a list of triples (tuples), or a PANDAS data frame.

Comment: Just responding directly to your title: NO. A variable references *one object*. You can tell it to reference *another object* with no problem, but it will only ever be referencing a single object at a time. Anything else would be pure chaos. You want some sort of *container*/*collection* from the sounds of it. But it isn't exactly clear what you want. In python *lists* (not arrays) don't have "columns".  It would really help if you gave a *simple example* of the behavior you are trying to accomplish. There is a lot of irrelevant detail in the code you posted.  Help us help you

Comment: I'd go either for a pandas dataframe or for a dictionary mapping numbers to tuples.

Comment: @Prune or a dictionary of lists...

Comment: Writing your own `class Boss` would be a good starting point. Then add attributes to that, and store them in a list. Implement `__eq__` on the class, and you can `find` in a list

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga To explain how I intend the code to work:

The user inputs a number from 1-4 to choose which boss they are interested in. Then I want to find the probability that the item is dropped (a successful trial) given the drop rate (probability of success) after a certain number of attempts (which will be an input variable). So I'd need to calculate a new variable for probability of success, which will depend on the value read from the list that contains the boss name, item name, and drop rate. The drop rate will be different depending on which boss is selected.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you would like to store some collection of data under a single entry.

Thinking in terms of "columns" is very limiting. Rather best to think in terms of documents/fields, in my opinion

```
boss_name = {
  "2": {
     "name": "Gregorovic", 
     "item": {"name": "Faceless mask", "rate": "1/1000"}
  }
}

ans = input("Which boss: ")
boss = boss_name[ans]["name"]
item = boss_name[ans]["item"]

print("You have selected {}; {} has a drop rate of {}".format(boss, item['name'], item['rate']))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works if I input 2 when prompted, but say if I wanted to input 1, it doesn't. Is there a way to get your code to work for any number I input? I've tried duplicating it below and changing "2" to "1" and updating the other names/numbers in that block, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `boss_name` is just a dictionary. I was creating a minimal example. Are you saying you don't know how to update a dictionary? Like `boss_name = {"1": {...},  "2": {...}, "3": {...}}` Note: If you always store numbers as keys, you should use a list of objects, not a dictionary at all

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to the "3rd column" into a new line. So according to that, if you want to hack more then you can just use:

```
pet_item_info = {
    "Vindicta and Gorvek" : "Imbued blade slice \n 1/2000",
    "Gregorovic" : "Faceless mask \n 1/1000"
}
```

The string operator `\n` is a line break, similarly for `<br>` in HTML.

You should definitely check out W3 school's [python tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datatypes.asp) though.

Otherwise yes, you can have multiple columns in various ways. As @OneCricketeer said, I would recommend writing a Boss class too.